# Add multiple Buttons in Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Can any one help me to add more than one custom button to the right bar of the navigation bar.
If possible please answer with the detail code, so that i can understand it properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

//add a right btn to the navigation bar

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f)];

UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
[btn1 setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customView addSubview:btn1];

UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
[btn2 setTitle:@"2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn2Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customView addSubview:btn2];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBtn];
```

Comment: I want to add two buttons and those are custom buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 5 there are this 4 methods available

```
- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items;
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items;
```

where you can set an array of `UIBarButtonItem`

example:

```
NSArray * buttons = @[button1,button2];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:buttons];
```