# UIBarbutton item allocation leak - iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uibarbuttonitem

I am declaring a property for the rightbutton toolbar and allocating it like this

```
if(self.toolBar == nil)
    self.toolBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.toolBar;


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    toolBar = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [toolBar release];
    [super dealloc];     
}
```

When I come to this screen for the second time(2nd time viewDidLoad called), the UIBarbuttonItem is leaking according to Instruments. What could be wrong?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: it may sound stupid, but are you definitely seeing this in the leaks instrument ? (as opposed to zombies or allocations)

Answer (score 2):

You're niling the toolbar property prematurely - viewDidUnload will be called before dealloc, thus dealloc will have no chance to release the barbutton, because `toolBar` points to **nil, not the object** (which will remain owned (release count of at least 1) but without reference).

Plus, since you're not using the dot notation (`self.toolBar`) to nil out the property, the old objects release count would not be decreased! So its retain count is at least 2 at the time your controller will quit.

I'd release the object right after assigning it to your property, because the setter method has retained it anyway (if you choose to retain it in the declaration). Later in viewDidUnload all you need to do is `self.toolBar = nil;` to really get rid of it.

Comment: ooh, your answer is much better than mine - I didn't notice the `toolBar = nil` in viewDidUnload at all!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I am trying out this code after your suggestion:    if(self.toolBar == nil)
        self.toolBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.toolBar;
    
    [self.toolBar release];......In dealloc, I have commented the release...and in viewDidUnload, I do self.toolBar = nil; The leak does not go away..

Answer (score 1):

I guess your property is something like this?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem toolBar;
```

This will perform a retain automatically for you but you are giving your property an already retained toobar item.

Try this instead :

```
if(toolBar == nil)
    toolBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.toolBar;
```

If you don't use `self.` it won't use the property and therefor won't have that extra retain :)

Comment: I had already tried that, but it did not work, hence changed it to a retained property.

Comment: @Toaster has spotted another leak you will need to fix as well - use his answer!

Comment: I just redid the whole thing based on this question and the link given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725721/add-multiple-buttons-in-navigation-bar and it works now!